# I'm running docker-compose up, terminal show me: (root) Additional property mongo is not allowed

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm practicing with Docker but I have this message in my terminal. Someone have any solution?

**my docker-compose**

```
mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports: 
  - "27017:27017"
  restart: always

web:
  build: .
  ports: 
  - "3000:3000"
  links: 
  - mongo
  command: node index.js
```

**Terminal:**

```
(root) Additional property mongo is not allowed
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing the `services` keyword.

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
 mongo:
  image: mongo
  ports: 
  - "27017:27017"
  restart: always
 .....
```

see the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Comment: Hi @navylover, thanks for your answer, I tried buy I'm continued with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, my problem was that **web** had the same level of services.

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports: 
    - "27017:27017"
    restart: always

  web:
    build: .
    ports: 
    - "3000:3000"
    links: 
    - mongo
    command: node index.js
```

Thanks for all.